# How to replace first three characters of a string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to replace first three characters of a string in oracle. Lets say i have 100 records of employee id, i need to replace first three characters of records between 30 to 50 out of 100.

- Input:111234,111235,111236,111237
- Output: 222234,222235,222236,222237 (Replace and update)

Comment: what to replace with

Comment: you want the query or update statement????

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Please post some actual code!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include an [MCVE] with details such as: your table structure (as text or code, not images); what you want to replace; what you want to replace it with; how you are ordering the data to find the 30th or 50th record; whether you want to update your table or just perform the replacement in a query; and your expected output (again, as text).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to replace the first 3 characters with `abc` for the 30th to 50th rows (ordered by some criteria) then:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN ROWNUM BETWEEN 30 AND 50
       THEN 'abc' || SUBSTR( your_column, 4 )
       ELSE your_column
       END AS replaced_value
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER BY <some_criteria>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
    SELECT * FROM ns_words;

    mine
    mini
    mani
    nikhil
    sugandh
    mining

    SELECT regexp_replace(a,'(.{3}(.*)$)','abc\2') FROM NS_WORDS;
    abce
    abci
    abci
    abchil
    abcandh
    abcing
```

for your query its like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(a,'(.{3}(.*)$)','abc\2') FROM NS_WORDS where col2 
between 30 and 50;
```

Comment: "replace first three characters of records between 30 to 50 out of 100" This does not address the OP's (unclear) requirement of updating only records between two bounds. Also, using regular expressions is overkill; you can just use `SUBSTR`.

Comment: @MT0 give it another column and do a where between 30 and 50 thats it